# Self-join with Laravel

Tags: laravel, self-join, eloquent

How can I do a self-join with Laravel 3 or 4?

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

     public function category ()
     {
          return $this->has_one('Category');
     }


}
```

Comment: Assuming you have a `category_id` on your Category that should be fine.  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a `category_id` column in your `Category` table, this should work just fine, recursively.